# Is it possible to use my PS Vita as additional PS3 controller?

Tags: ps3, controllers, ps-vita

As the title states: can I register my PS vita as an additional controller to an PS3 system? I want to play split-screen games without buying a new controller.

I've already searched around the web. All I found were some news entries that stated some people managed to get this to work, but they did not mention *how* this can be achieved.

I've also tried to connect to the PS3 system using remote play and add the other controllers, but this did not work either, because the screen just says that my Vita is connected using remote play. "Cross Play" is also not what I am looking for. I just want to use my Vita like a traditional controller.

So is this possible?

**Edit:**

Just to make some things clear: I know about the features "Remote Play" and "Cross Play", but they are **not** what I am looking for, since they are all serving different purposes.

Comment: I think this is possible but only if the game explicitly supports it, which I don't think any really do right now.  I'm not really sure on this, just throwing out what my impression was.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use your Vita as a PS3 controller! Go to the remote play tab on your Vita, and there will be a second tab (it's blue). With the new update on the Vita, it allows you to turn your Vita into a controller. I haven't tried it to see how you connect it, but it was just recently added. If you can't see it, update your PS Vita.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try this when I'm back home :-)

Comment: Note that this claims to require software to support "cross controller" functionality...not sure what all does/doesn't support that, honestly

Comment: How do the triggers work? Doesn't the Vita only have one L + R trigger, while the PS3 has 2? Also, what about L3 and R3? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can use L2 and R2 with your touchpad on the back of your PS Vita system. Sliding on the right side is R2, sliding on the left side is L2 ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't hook it up as a traditional controller, per se. At least, Sony haven't given it that functionality. There are probably some homebrew hacks somewhere around that enable it, but using those could seriously affect your PS3.

I know you said crossplay isn't what you're looking for, but in case anyone else is interested, here's the link to the list of games that support it: http://uk.playstation.com/ps3/support/games/detail/linked513180/item513385/PS3-games-compatible-with-PS-Vita/

Comment: I'll take a look at this, too :)

Comment: The pedant in me insists I edit 'persay' to 'per se' but it's not a big enough edit...

Comment: @Rob I changed it for you :)

Answer (score -1):

You can only use it on the XMB menu and in the internet browser.